# Как одну функцию тестировать разными значениями?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Решил проверить свои функции с помощью юнит тестов, но для данного кода

```
import unittest
import calculator

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_solve(self):
    self.assertEqual(calculator.solve('110 * 180 +(360 - 200 + (3 - 2))'), 19961.0)
    self.assertEqual(calculator.solve('200'), 200)
    self.assertEqual(calculator.solve('(6+10-4)/(1+1*2)+1'), 5)
    self.assertEqual(calculator.solve('(100)'), 100)
```

выполняется только один тест. В коде я тестирую функцию solve. Что можно сделать, чтоб одну функцию можно было тестировать разными значениями?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы и так здесь тестируете `calculator.solve` разными значениями

Comment: @andreymal а, моя ошибка, извините)

Comment: А вот то, что в одном тесте четыре независимых assert'а это плоховато. В идеальном мире стремятся разделить тесты так, чтобы на одну test_чтототам функцию был ровно один assert (это не всегда возможно, но здесь вполне возможно)